# Redirect outputs of multiple commands to a single file

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file

I am very new to windows batch scripting, this can be a silly question. 
I am running following batch file: "traffic.bat"

```
start /B netperf.exe -H HOST IP >> file.txt
start /B netperf.exe -H HOST IP >> file.txt
start /B netperf.exe -H HOST IP >> file.txt
...
```

The first command is working properly but for further commands, i am getting following error:
"The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process"

I know on linux this works fine: "traffic.sh"

```
netperf.exe -H HOST IP >> file.txt &
netperf.exe -H HOST IP >> file.txt &
netperf.exe -H HOST IP >> file.txt &
```

I want to achieve very similar to the "traffic.sh".

Answer (score 3):

The reason its doing so is that all the processes are trying to use the file at once. You need to wait for each one to complete its task. All you have to do is include `/wait` parameter for te `start` command. Try this:

```
start /wait /B netperf.exe -H HOST IP >> file.txt
start /wait /B netperf.exe -H HOST IP >> file.txt
start /wait /B netperf.exe -H HOST IP >> file.txt
...
```

And that should work fine!

Mona

Comment: Just asking, do they have to be in the same file? Even if they do, what you could do is put them in seperate files and then append them all into one "file.txt" Other then that I don't know whats wrong...

Comment: yes, they are in same file. I have put them in same file because i want to execute all commands simultaneously.

Comment: @Jaiswal Why don't you try either `call` or not including `start /b` and refering to it as an operable program. That might work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to redirect the output of multiple commands into the same file all at once:

```
...
(
start /B netperf.exe -H HOST IP
start /B netperf.exe -H HOST IP
start /B netperf.exe -H HOST IP
::Add more commands if needed
)>>file.txt
```

Unfortunately, I have no way to test if this will work in your current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cygwin? I think that your "traffic.sh" script might work with some minor changes (perhaps interpreter and line endings)